# Which implemtation of JSF 1.1 to use MyFaces or Sun RI

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces

We want make a choice between SUN RI 1.1 JSF implementaiton and MyFaces. Appserver we will be using is Weblogic 8.1. Could you please provide main points for Comparison between the two 
Which one is better. Can we use Facelets in SUN RI 1.1_02.

Which is the better choice if want to move the Application to JSF 1.2 and JDK 1.5 in Future.

Answer (score 1):

RI 1.1_02 is fine. Facelets requires at least Servlet 2.4. Weblogic 8.1 however supports max Servlet 2.3. So you'll have to stick to RI 1.1_02 with JSP.